# WCF REST + Windsor error handling

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, castle-windsor

I want to handle application's internal exceptions in a consistent way so that REST web services return errors in a [RESTful way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942951/rest-api-error-return-good-practices).

I'm using Castle's WCF integration and I couldn't find any good sources on how to do handle errors using `WcfIntegration.WindsorServiceHostFactory`. The only solution that comes to mind is to use Castle's interceptors on web service methods to catch "internal" exceptions and translate them to HTTP response properties (for example: `KeyNotFoundException` would be translated to `404 Not Found` status code).

Are there any better ways? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about standard WCF `IErrorHandler` ?

Comment: Yes, this will probably be the best option. Once I find out how to wire the darn thing into WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287802/access-request-body-in-a-wcf-restful-service/1288257#1288257) question.  I think the reason for the HttpContext.Current being null may be related.